# Get Array of LXD Snapshot Names

Tags: bash, shell-script, lxc, lxd

I am pretty green when it comes to `grep`, can someone point out how I can get an array in `bash` of the list of snapshot names (**NOTE:** just the names) when I do a `lxc info mycontainer` ?

My current results are:

```
root@hosting:~/LXC-Commander# lxc info mycontainer --verbose
Name: mycontainer
Remote: unix:/var/lib/lxd/unix.socket
Architecture: x86_64
Created: 2017/05/01 21:27 UTC
Status: Running
Type: persistent
Profiles: mine
Pid: 23304
Ips:
  eth0: inet    10.58.122.150   vethDRS01G
  eth0: inet6   fd9b:16e1:3513:f396:216:3eff:feb1:c997  vethDRS01G
  eth0: inet6   fe80::216:3eff:feb1:c997        vethDRS01G
  lo:   inet    127.0.0.1
  lo:   inet6   ::1
Resources:
  Processes: 1324
  Memory usage:
    Memory (current): 306.63MB
    Memory (peak): 541.42MB
  Network usage:
    eth0:
      Bytes received: 289.16kB
      Bytes sent: 881.73kB
      Packets received: 692
      Packets sent: 651
    lo:
      Bytes received: 1.51MB
      Bytes sent: 1.51MB
      Packets received: 740
      Packets sent: 740
Snapshots:
  2017-04-29-mycontainer (taken at 2017/04/29 21:54 UTC) (stateless)
  2017-04-30-mycontainer (taken at 2017/04/30 21:54 UTC) (stateless)
  2017-05-01-mycontainer (taken at 2017/05/01 21:54 UTC) (stateless)
```

With my ultimate goal of simply containing an array such as: `2017-04-29-mycontainer 2017-04-30-mycontainer 2017-05-01-mycontainer`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `lxc list --format=json` you get a JSON document with a lot of information about all the various available containers.

`lxc list mycontainer --format=json` limits this to the containers whose names start with the string `mycontainer` (use `'mycontainer$'` for an exact match).

Parsing JSON is generally safer than parsing a text document that is almost free form.

To extract the names of the snapshots [using `jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```
$ lxc list mycontainer --format=json | jq -r '.[].snapshots[].name'
```

This will give you a list like

```
2017-04-29-mycontainer
2017-04-30-mycontainer
2017-05-01-mycontainer
```

To put this into an array in `bash`:

```
snaps=( $( lxc list mycontainer --format=json | jq -r '.[].snapshots[].name' ) )
```

Just be aware that if you do this, snapshot names with characters that are special to the shell (`*?[`) will cause file name globbing to happen.  You can prevent this with `set -f` before the command (and `set +f` after).

If you just want to loop over the snapshots:

```
lxc list mycontainer --format=json | jq -r '.[].snapshots[].name' |
while read snap; do
   # do something with "$snap"
done
```

Comment: nice mate!.   I have to install `jq` tho ;)    Will let ya know.  Yeah, the nameshot names will always be named YYYY-MM-DD-mycontainer :)

Comment: strangely: `snaps=( $( lxc list mycontainer --format=json | jq -r '.[].snapshots[].name' ) )` doesn't return anything, yet without assigning it to a variable returns me the full snapshot name (tho, it includes the container name as well...  like: `mycontainer/2017-05-01-mycontainer` ...

Comment: @Kevin check the contents of the array with `echo "${snaps[@]}"`.  The installation of `lxc` that I use seems to return the names without the container name prepended... Odd.

Comment: Aye
`root@hosting:~# snaps=( $( lxc list kevinpirnie --format=json | jq -r '.[].snapshots[].name' ) )
root@hosting:~# echo "${snaps[@]}"
kevinpirnie/2017-05-01-kevinpirnie kevinpirnie/2017-05-02-kevinpirnie
root@hosting:~#
`

Comment: I have v.2.0.9 installed on ubuntu 16.04.2

Comment: @Kevin Same as me. Well, if you have one snapshot name in a variable `$snap`, then `snap="${snap#*/}"` will remove whatever is in front of the `/` (including the `/`).

Comment: Appreciate it mate :)

Comment: Actually.  It may workout better with the full name anyways.   I'll be using this to cycle through the snapshots to delete the oldest (out of say 7 days worth) anyways :D